# Resizing parent div according to its child div

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-float

I am very bad at CSS. I want to resize the parent div based on height of child div. Below is my html code.

```
<div id="mainPanel" class="tabPanel">
     <div class="ui-corner-all ui-widget-content grid_container" style="padding: 5px; margin: 5px; text-align: left;">
         <div align="left">
            <div id="subTabs" style="width:500px">
               <div class="ui-layout-content">
                  <div id="Form1">
                   </div>

                   <div id="Form2">
                   </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Inside form1 and form2 div's I am dynamically populating components which may grow till any height. I tried with overflow:auto in all the parent div's , but no luck.  Any help will really appreciated.

Comment: some css is very much welcome...And besides the parent always resizes to that of the size of the childrens space if not anything else is declared

Comment: @Breezer brings up a point I was going to ask. What are you declaring the sizes of Form1 and Form2 as?

Comment: Use firebug in Firefox to figure out your problem.

Comment: I am declaring sizes as style="height: 740px; width: 100%; for Form1 and Form2.

Comment: you can't define height if you want later resize it, or you have to change it when new content is loaded

Comment: change `hight` to `min-height` and it will grow to the worlds end

Comment: Impossible to answer without CSS posted.

Comment: @Mamadum you CAN define if you want. The problem is with the parent, not with the children...

Answer (score 0):

The parent always resizes to that of the size of the children's space if not anything else is declared. If you've set a fixed height diffrent browsers will behave diffrently, some will expand some will hide and others will scroll. You can simply fix this by either
changing `height` to `min-height` or remove the `height` declaration all together.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't have to do anything special to have the parent DIV as high as the children blocks. Maybe there is something wrong with the script...

If some children is floating, try `overflow:hidden;` with the parent DIV or other "clear fix" CSS trick...